# How to nullify one of the axes of rotation in a rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, rotations

Let's say that I've got a matrix with some rotation stored. Now I want to somehow make a $y$-rotation equal $0$ (or rather make it equal to the starting moment without rotation). How would I do it?

I thought about multiplying the current rotation matrix by the inverse Euler's formula for rotating around the $y$-axis, with pre-calculated angle from starting rotation quaternion of the unwanted rotation, but this is just a theoretical idea.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. Are you saying you have the matrix for a rotation around the vector $(x,y,z)$ (with angle equal to $\|(x,y,z)\|$), and you want to find the matrix for a rotation around the vector $(x,0,z)$?

Comment: Yes, you have understood my question right. Saying it simpler, I want to zero the roll rotation.

Comment: I found a better way around for my problem than manipulating the rotation matrix [link to my original problem](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72950/how-can-i-restrict-the-rotation-of-an-object-to-a-subset-of-axes-using-quaternio/), but I'm still concerned with my question.